# MongoDB: How do I define a variable in an aggregation stage?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to write an aggregation pipeline function that categorizes a list of users on the basis of a criteria. I intend to make it generic by using the criteria as a variable, which will ultimately be my `$group` stage's `_id` field.

[Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#user-variables) mention that I can use the value of a variable using the '$$'. However, no information exists on how do I define such a user variable. So I thought normally defined variables in python might work probably.

Here's the fucntion I wrote:

```py
def categorize_by(criteria) -> List:
    return [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$$criteria",
                "count": {"$sum": 1},
                "projects": {
                    "$push": {
                        "_id": "$_id",
                        "name": "$name",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ]
```

However, I end up getting the following error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Use of undefined variable: criteria`

How do I define the variable?

Comment: If you're using python3, you can do `f"${criteria}"`. Right now you're not using the python variable at all.

Comment: @RobertSeaman, Thanks! That helps resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing mongo variables and application variables.

The documentation is about mongo variables.
The system variables you refer to are always available and are defined by mongo.
User variables can be defined in some stages like [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html).

Application variables follow application language standards.
The pipeline in python is just a dict - use any language constructs to build the pipeline dynamically depending on runtime parameters.

In your case it could be as simple as

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": criteria,
        "count": {"$sum": 1},
```

Where `criteria` can be either a string, a number, a dict, or a compatible object, e.g. `bson.objectid.ObjectId` since it is `_id` field.

The key difference is application variables are defined on the application level and cannot be changed once the query is sent to mongo. The pipeline variables are defined within the pipeline itself from document's data or mongo functions during execution of the query.